# Dot '.' in XML-Tags / Transforming w. XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I've got an xml which shoule be transformed using XSLT but there are "." in the Tag and
in cause of that it doesn't work. But the . is allowed in XML-Tags.
Can anybody give me a hint on transforming such a file:
XML:

```
<root.element>
   <test.element>Hello World</test.element>
</root.element>
```

XSLT:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
   <test><xsl:value-of select="root.element/test.element"/></test>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: What XSLT Transformer (Implementation) are you using. It sounds like a bug in the transformer itself.

Comment: Define: "it doesn't work", since this is quite a broad statement.

Answer (score 0):

xsltproc (libxslt) transforms it properly. But you may try to push it in predicate:

```
<xsl:value-of select="node()[name()='test.element']"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

It should work. Tried it with the MS XSLT parser and it works okay.

I did wonder if the problem is in the XPath expression as the dot character has special meaning in XPath, but seems okay.

What is the exact error?